# How to sync a code window and solution explorer in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

If a have a code window open in Visual Studio, how can I quickly have the Solution Navigator or Solution Explorer show the current file is open?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General -> 
Track Active Item in Solution Explorer
```

Comment: The quick launch in VS 2015 is really helpful here: ctrl+Q type track active item. Then you'll find it.

Comment: Or do it once using CTRL + [, S

Answer (score 10):

Resharper?
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>?

:D

Comment: You might be right! On the other side are there any developers out there not using Visual Studio + Resharper? That would be really weird, right?

Answer (score 5):

With larger solutions, I find the `Track Active Item` option annoying as it often rearranges the view in Solution Explorer as I move from one code window to the next.

My preference is to use an extension called [Code Maid](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496?SRC=VSIDE), which allows you to find the item in the Solution Explorer via a context menu popup or keyboard shortcut.  Has other features that you may find useful as well.

Comment: Code Maid works great, has a shortcut that instantly shows the current file.

Answer (score 1):

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ef4ac3e9-d056-4383-8ca2-11721bd879b4
Here is a plugin which does that. It is also provided with on/off button which makes it comfortable to use.

Answer (score 1):

There is also native shortcut in VS - `CTRL + [, CTRL + S` by default. 
See keyboard shortcut to command `SolutionExplorer.SyncWithActiveDocument`

No plugins needed since at least VS 2017.